# The box is not centering and is also moving the background image along with it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to centre the **black box** on the webpage, but whenever I try to adjust the padding of `#banner_image` the **black box** starts moving up and down and whenever I try to adjust **margins** of `#banner_content` which contains the black box to center it the bg image starts scrolling.

I'm not being able to understand what is happening around here, can someone please explain?

```css
    #banner_image{
    background: url(../Images/intro-bg_1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-size: cover;
}

    #banner_content{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    max-width: 660px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 6%;
    padding-bottom: 6%;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
   <div id="banner_image">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="banner_content">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #banner_image{
    background: url(./bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    /* Adjust  the values as you need them */
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    /* Use the container to center the black box */
    .container {
      position: relative;
      /* Adjust  values to what you need. Remember to always have a set width and height if you want your elements to not move around the page and cause cumulative layout shift problems */
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    #banner_content{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    }


  </style>

<div id="banner_image">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="banner_content">
            
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

[image: Result should be something like this]

Comment: Thanx, it worked but my webpage is scrolling despite not having any content, I just have a fixed navbar to the top and a footer, but the image is scrolling down, why is that?

Comment: I can't know exactly, but it might be due to image aspect ratio or because of the modified values of height and width. Try adding  
#banner_image{
    background: url(./bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    /* Adjust  the values as you need them */
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

I made the width and height equal to the width of the screen and height of the screen. When you add a header and a footer. Those parameters change. depending on the height of the footer and header.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please upvote it when you can. Thank you.

Also as an additional resource. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

To know more in-depth how this is achieved